# Error while using with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(...) in Python

Tags: python, smtp

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

email="....."
password="....."
print(email)
msg=EmailMessage()
msg['Subject']='AR'
msg['From']=email
msg['To']='......'
msg.set_content('Ok it works')
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',465) as smtp:
    smtp.login(email,password)
smtp.sendmail(email,"reciever_email",msg)
```

Error occurring:

> SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first

I don't understand where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `with` context manager defines `smtp` *for the duration of the block*. You are exiting the block prematurely, so `smtp` is no longer defined, and the connection to the server is terminated.

The fix is trivial; indent the last line so it's inside the `with` block.

Comment: Ok.thanks.It worked.but there were some other error in code as well.This code puts the kernel in infinite loop or something. Should I put the correct code here as well?

Comment: I don't think you can crash your kernel with this. Probably no need to post a separate answer if it's just yet another copy of the standard example of how to send email.

Comment: Ok. And Kernel didn't crash but  it kept running for around 20 min with any result or anything,There are a few errors in last line of codes.Any way thanks for your help.It was a nice and precise solution.